# $f'(c) \ge 0 , \forall c \in (a,b)$ then $f$ is increasing in $[a,b]$ , proof of this without Mean Value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a function differentiable in $(a,b)$ , it is known that if $f'(c) \ge 0 , \forall c \in (a,b)$ then $f$ is increasing in $[a,b]$ and this can be proved by Lagrange Mean value theorem ; I would like to know , is there any other proof of this ?

Comment: Is Taylor theorem okay?

Comment: @Moron Aw hell no, that's disgusting and requires use of the MVT to prove

Comment: @Moron: No , Taylor theorem is NOT okay

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that there are points $c$, $d$ with $a<c<d<b$ such that
$${f(d)-f(c)\over d-c}=-p<0\ .$$
I claim that there is a point $\xi\in[c,d]$ with $f'(\xi)\leq-p$.

*Proof.* Using binary division we can find an increasing  sequence $(c_n)_{n\geq0}$ and a decreasing sequence $(d_n)_{n\geq0}$ with $$c\leq c_n<d_n\leq d,\qquad d_n-c_n={d-c\over2^n}\qquad(n\geq0)\ ,$$
such that
$${f(d_n)-f(c_n)\over d_n-c_n}\leq -p\qquad(n\geq0)\ .\tag{1}$$
The $c_n$ and the $d_n$ have a common limit point $\xi\in[c,d]$. If
$$\xi=c_n\qquad(n\geq n_0)$$ one immediately concludes from $(1)$ that $f'(\xi)\leq-p$. Otherwise we may assume $c_n<\xi<d_n$ for all $n\geq0$. Rewriting the left hand side of $(1)$ we then can say say that
$${\xi-c_n\over d_n-c_n}{f(\xi)-f(c_n)\over \xi-c_n}+{d_n-\xi\over d_n-c_n}{f(d_n)-f(\xi)\over d_n-\xi}\leq -p\qquad(n\geq0)\ .\tag{2}$$
Now let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then for some sufficiently large $n$ the difference quotients of $f$ in $(2)$ are $\geq f'(\xi)-\epsilon$, and this implies
$$f'(\xi)-\epsilon\leq -p\ .$$
Since this is true for all $\epsilon>0$ the claim follows.

Comment: This looks cool. You start with the negative slope of chord and show that the slope of tangent must also be negative somewhere. +1.

Comment: @Christian Blatter: +1. This is the intuitive proof! On the same note, sliding the half segment would produce a chord with half the base and same slope, approaching a tangent, another proof of MVP.  On another note: for vector valued functions we have MVP only as inequality $||f(b) - f(a) || \le \sup ||f'(t)||\cdot (b-a)$ and this method would work again.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone reading this answer: it is somewhat wrong. Please check comments.

If I may assume $f'(c)>0$:

For every $x \in [a,b]$ we have an interval $I_x$ which by definition of the limit (the derivative), we have $f$ increasing on $I_x$ *. Then $\bigcup_{x \in [a,b]} I_x=[a,b]$, and since $[a,b]$ is compact we can find a finite subcover $\bigcup_{i=1,...,n} I_{x_i}=[a,b]$. $f$ is increasing on each interval $I_{x_i}$, and for any two points $p<q$ with $p,q \in [a,b]$ we can find intermediate points $r_j$ ($r_1=p$,...,$r_m=q$) such that $\forall j$, $r_j$ and $r_{j+1}$ are both in $I_{x_i}$ for some $i$. Then, $\forall j$, we have $f(r_j)<f(r_{j+1})$ and hence $f(p)<f(q)$.

*Suppose $f'(x)=c>0$. Then $\exists  \delta$ such that $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}>\frac{c}{2}>0$ for $|y-x|<\delta$. Define $I_x$ to be the interval $(x-\frac{\delta}{2},x+\frac{\delta}{2})$. Then $f$ strictly increasing on $I_x$.

**Method 2**, *with $f'(c) \geq 0$*. Every assumption used here can be proven without use of the MVT.

Simply note that $f(x)=\int_a^xf'(t) \mathrm{dt}$. For $y>x$, $f(y)-f(x)=\int_x^yf'(t)\mathrm{dt}$. Since $f'(t) \geq 0$ for $t \in [x,y]$ we have $f(y)-f(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: I like the idea for Method 1, there is a tiny fixable problem, $f'(x) >0$ does not imply $f$ strictly increasing around $x$, only the weaker: around $x$,  $\ x_1 \le x \le x_2$, $\ x_1 <x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) <f(x_2)$.

Comment: @orangeskid good point... Fixing it requires a quite substantial change of the proof where we need to prove the existence of a subcover with certain nice properties, unless I'm missing something

Comment: Your proof is flawed because sign of derivative at a single point does not ensure its monotone nature in neighborhood of that point. See my answer for a proper approach to the proof of the question posted here.

Comment: The pathological examples are not differentiable everywhere in the interval. In fact it is a theorem that any function which is differentiable everywhere in a compact interval and of bounded variation is absolutely continuous. Hence an increasing, everywhere differentiable function is absolutely continuous. The fact that the Cantor function is merely differentiable almost everywhere is important.

Comment: @Shakespeare: I think you can fix it by using the weaker conclusion that I stated above $x_1 \le x \le x_2$, $x_1 < x_2$. I like the segment interlacing, it's very intuitive.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh it can be rectified using a special subcover, just I have not bothered to do it

Comment: @Shakespeare: It is better that to write your details in the solution and especially delete the line "That $f$ is strictly increasing on $I_{x}$. There is so much confusion among students regarding the theory of calculus. And hence we should try not to write statements which are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all this is a very good question (+1 to OP for the same). Without using MVT the proof is really tricky.

First I prove under the stronger condition $f'(x) > 0$. Let's then assume this to be the case and prove that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing.

There are two proofs possible as far as I know:

1) **Proof using Rolle's Theorem**: While MVT is not allowed here I would like to use Rolle's in a very different way (so as not to repeat a demonstration of something equivalent to MVT). Let $c < d$ be two points in $[a, b]$. We will prove that $f(c) < f(d)$. Clearly we can't have $f(c) = f(d)$ as that would lead to vanishing of derivative $f'(x)$ somewhere in $(c, d)$ (Rolle's theorem).

I will now show that we can't have $f(c) > f(d)$. Suppose on the contrary that $f(c) > f(d)$. Then we can see that $f'(d) > 0$ implies that there is a point $c < e < d$ such that $f(e) < f(d)$ so that $f(e) < f(d) < f(c)$ and hence by intermediate value property there is a point $x_{0}$ between $c, e$ such that $f(x_{0}) = f(d)$. This would again lead to vanishing of derivative $f'(x)$ (Rolle's theorem). Hence it follows that we can't have $f(c) > f(d)$ and therefore we have $f(c) < f(d)$.

2) **Proof Using Dedekind's Theorem**: This is bit tricky. If $f'(x) > 0$ it means that there is a neigborhood $I_{x}$ of $x$ such that if $y \in I_{x}, y < x$ then $f(y) < f(x)$ and if $y \in I_{x}, y > x$ then $f(y) > f(x)$. Let's call this behavior of $f$ as **$f$ is strictly increasing at $x$**.

Now $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ means that $f$ is strictly increasing at all points of $[a, b]$. Let $c < d$ be two points in $[a, b]$. We show that $f(c) < f(d)$. We divide all points $x$ of $[c, b]$ into sets $L$ and $R$ in the following manner. A point $x$ lies in $L$ if for all points $y \in [c, x]$ we have $f(y) > f(c)$. Otherwise $x$ lies in $R$. Clearly $L$ is non-empty $f'(c) > 0$ implies existence of points to the right of $c$ where $f$ takes values greater than $f(c)$. If $R$ is also non-empty then by Dedekind's theorem **there is a number $\alpha$ such that all numbers less than $\alpha$ lie in $L$ and all those greater than $\alpha$ lie in $R$**. Note that $\alpha > c$ and we will show that $\alpha = b$ so that $R$ is empty.

Suppose that $\alpha < b$. If $f(\alpha) \geq f(c)$ then we can find points to the right of $\alpha$ at which $f(x) > f(\alpha) \geq f(c)$ so that points to the right of $\alpha$ also belong to $L$. This contradicts the conclusion of Dedekind's theorem mentioned in previous paragraph. On the other hand if $f(\alpha) < f(c)$ then there are points to the left of $\alpha$ at which $f(x) < f(\alpha) < f(c)$ and this would mean again violate the conclusion that numbers less than $\alpha$ lie in $L$. Hence it follows that we must have $\alpha = b$. Note further that $\alpha = b$ must lie in $L$. If $b \in R$ then every number less than $b$ lies in $L$ which means that at these points $f(x) > f(c)$, but since $b \in R$ so there must be some point left of $b$ for which $f(x) \leq f(c)$.

We have thus show that all points of $[c, b]$ lie in $L$ and by definition of $L$ we must have $f(c) < f(x)$ for $x \in (c, b]$. Since $d \in (c, b]$ it follows that $f(c) < f(d)$.

The proof for the case when $f'(x) \geq 0$ is completed by the technique of dealing with $f(x) + \epsilon\cdot x$ and letting $\epsilon \to 0$ (mentioned by orangeskid).

**Note**: Both the proofs are taken from my beloved book "A Course of Pure Mathematics" by G. H. Hardy. Also I had assumed differentiability at the end points of interval. This is not really necessary and can be taken care of by using continuity of $f$ and end points. We can assume that points $c, d$ in the proofs above belong to $(a, b)$ instead of $[a, b]$. Suppose that $a < x < b$ and take $y, z$ such that $a < y < z < x < b$. Then $f(y) < f(z) < f(x)$. Taking limit as $y \to a^{+}$ we get $f(a) \leq f(z) < f(x)$ so that $f(a) < f(x)$ and similarly we can show that $f(x) < f(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Shakespeare: Method $1$.

For any $\epsilon >0$ the function 
$$f(x) + \epsilon\cdot x$$

is strictly increasing. Take $\epsilon \to 0$.

Let's prove that $f$ is strictly increasing under the stronger hypothesis $f'>0$.

Consider the set
$$\{x \  | \ f \ \text{strictly increasing on}\  [a,x]\}$$

It contains $a$ so it's nonvoid. Let $x^*$ be its supremum. Then $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,x^*)$. Now since $f'(x^*)>0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ so that 
$$x^* - \delta < x_1 \le x \le x_2 <x^* + \delta \ \text{and}\  x_1 < x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) < f(x_2)$$

We conclude that $f^*$ is strictly increasing on $[a,x^*]$, and, if $x^* < b$,  that   $f^*$ strictly increasing on $[a,x^*+ \delta)$. Therefore, $x^*=b$ and 
$f^*$ strictly increasing on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, I was a bit lazy to do something like this myself. It doesn't really stand as an answer the way it is though. Either expand, post as a comment, or we can merge the answers

Comment: @Shakespeare: Feel free to include this in your proof; you also need a tiny fix, basically $\lim{ x_1 \nearrow x, x_2 \searrow x}\frac{ f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}=f'(x)$ is the correct limit.

Comment: How do you know that $x\mapsto f(x)+\epsilon x$ is strictly increasing? If the MVT is forbidden we have to reprove it somehow.

Comment: @Christian Blatter: Based on some other proofs that use the stronger condition $f'>0$. This only shows that you can reduce to $f'>0$.