# One implication in $f'(x) \ge 0 \iff f \ \text{is monotonically increasing}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am trying to understand why $f'(x) \ge 0 \iff f \ \text{is monotonically increasing}$ with the usual set of assumptions. To do this I am trying to prove the two implications. It is relatively easy to get why $\impliedby$ holds since an increasing $f$
 implies$${f(x_0+h)-f(x_0) \over h} \ge 0$$
no matter what the $h$ is.

The second implication $\implies$ proves to be more tricky. I am able to show it rewriting the mean value theorem as

$$f(b)=f'(\xi)(b-a)+f(a)$$
and concluding that for $a,b$ satisfying $a<b$ we do get $f(b)\ge f(a)$.

Is there an easier way to see $\implies$ without using the mean value theorem?

Comment: I think this is the usual way. You can go look at how the mean value theorem is proven and use this instead of the theorem as black box.

Comment: The mean value theorem is the proper tool here (as I see it). The MVT itself is a consequence of Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [$f'(c) \ge 0 , \forall c \in (a,b)$ then $f$ is increasing in $[a,b]$ , proof of this without Mean Value theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960433/fc-ge-0-forall-c-in-a-b-then-f-is-increasing-in-a-b-proof-of)

Comment: @BrandonSweeting FCT, in its usual formulations, talks about the primitive of a *continuous* function, so you'd technically need $f$ to be $C^1$ for it to be usable. However, I gather the "usual assumptions" are "$f$ differentiable".

Comment: Some clarification on what the *"usual set of assumptions"* are would be helpful, as possible answers depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with $f'(x) \geq 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Taking $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.
\begin{align*}
f(x+h) - f(x) = \int_{x}^{x+h} f'(t) dt \geq 0
\end{align*}
Rearranging, $f(x + h) \geq f(x)$.

Edit: this assumes integrability of $f'(x)$.

Comment: This is what I had in mind. To clarify, the second part of the FTC doesn't assume continuity of the derivative in being able to compute its definite integrals via its primitive?

Comment: @BrandonSweeting: But is requires integrability (Lebesgue or Riemann) of the derivative, as far as I know.

Comment: And btw, the proof of the second part of FTC (as given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Proof_of_the_second_part) *uses* the MVT.

Comment: That would definitely make sense. There seems to be something subtle (or not so subtle) that I'm missing.

Comment: You can prove the FTC without the MVT.

Comment: Sorry about this, yeah. Under minimal assumptions on f this would not work then.

Comment: How is that so?

Comment: The derivative of a function is not necessarily integrable. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257069/what-is-an-example-that-a-function-is-differentiable-but-derivative-is-not-riema

Comment: Does this mean I should delete the post? I'm new here so I don't know.